# Scalability of scheduled database jobs

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a hypothetical cloud based alarm clock project that allows users to schedule a non repeating "wake up call" for the date and time of their choosing. This system needs to scale to very large numbers. Don't worry about things like number of telephone lines etc.

Question: how would you query the data to know who needs to be called right now. Are scheduled jobs the best approach and if so do you have one job per scheduled call or do you have one job wake up periodically and do a catch all query? If jobs are not the best then what would you do?

Note: Im not looking for code. I would like to know what the architectural strategy would be to best approach this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your hardware is not infinitely fast, then you have to accept the possibility of inaccuracies, meaning that a user who wanted to wake up at 12:00 may in fact be woken up at 12:00:00.002.  They should not mind.

Based on this premise, you do not need one job per scheduled call, (you would need an infinitely large number of such jobs, and that would not scale very well,) nor do you need a job that wakes up periodically and does a catch-all query.  (That would be seriously lame.)

All you need is a single timer.

From all alarms, you disregard those that were to fire in the past, and from the rest you pick the one which is closest to "now".  This is, for all practical purposes, the next alarm to fire among all alarms waiting to fire.  So, you set your timer to fire for that alarm.

If a new alarm is created before the timer fires, you see whether it is closer to now, and if it is, then you modify the timer, so that the timer is always set to fire at the time for the next alarm.

Once the timer fires, you wake up the user.  If you do not have an infinitely high time resolution, (meaning that more than one user may need to be woken up at the exact same time,) you wake up all users that should be woken up.

Then, you repeat the query which finds the future alarm which is closest to "now", you re-initialize your timer, and you wait for the next alarm.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. Are you saying you would constantly poll the database? Also i edited the answer to change "infinite" to "very large number" thanks.

Comment: You would only poll the database each time the timer fires. (And of course each time an alarm is added.) That's very different from constantly polling the database.

Comment: Im not convinced that polling is the most elegant solution in any situation. I did up vote your answer but im not convinced is a very robust way to solve this since polling is notorious for not being very efficient.

Comment: Polling can pretty much be *defined* as an operation that is regularly repeated in order to check whether an event has occurred, as opposed to an operation that is only performed when the event has occurred.  In this sense, it was not even correct on my behalf to write "you would only poll the database each time the timer fires".  Re-read the above as "you would only access the database each time the timer fires".  **This is not polling**.

Comment: Not convinced your answer works  Assume no new alarms are set during this example. A single timer fires in time for the next alarm at time T. At this time there may be a number of alarms N scheduled. Say that the timer hands off this list to another system as not not spend time doing the calls. Handing off this list takes time H. You can see that H increases with N. It is possible to reach a point in which N is large enough such that H takes more time than T + X minutes, where X would be the next time the timer was supposed to fire. At this point the system begins to fall behind.